# User name can not contain null value

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert two values to mysql database through two textboxes using WPF and C#. I am connecting to the database successfuly but when I try to insert the data I get error: Column "user_name" can not be null. What is really confusing be is that I am entering data in the first and the second textboxes. It seems that the data to inserted in the textboxes is not passed. My question is do you know where is the problem and how to fix it?

PS: my database is very simple contain id as int16 auto incremented, name as varchar100 and user_password as varchar100

Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=tara.rdb.superhosting.bg;user=sozopouk;password=27051996;database=sozopouk_test2;");
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("Insert into niki2 values (@id,@name, @user_password)", con);

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value=textBox2.Text;

        con.Open();
        da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Guys after I did couple of changes I am getting this error message:

**Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'**

Here is edited code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=tara.rdb.superhosting.bg;user=sozopouk;password=27051996;database=sozopouk_test2;");
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki (name, user_password) VALUES (@name, @user_password)", con);

            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value=textBox2.Text;

            con.Open();
            da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
```

When I replace name with user_name and try to insert data I get an error ** Column "user_name" cannot be null**

The affected line is :

```
da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: I know you didn't ask about this specifically, but I recommend getting into the habit of always including explicit column names in `INSERT` statements. In some of my earliest database code, it was a total p.i.t.a. to have to go back and fix things when the database schema changed to add columns.

Comment: did u check if @user_name is given as notnull field in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I find the problem causing me this exception. As you can see my old code:

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki (name, user_password) VALUES (@name, @user_password)", con);

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value=textBox2.Text;
```

enter code here

What I did was to replace the

> @ with ?

And basically my code looked like :

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki (name, user_password) VALUES (?name, ?user_password)", con);

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("?name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;

da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("?user_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value=textBox2.Text;

enter code here
```

Thanks to all who involved in the discussion!

Answer (score 3):

Look at your code:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_id", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = "";
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "";
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
   textBox2.Text;
```

Now look at what you've said:

> It seems that the data to inserted in the textboxes is not passed.

Look at the code again. Look at the value being used for `user_name` (and indeed `user_id`). How is that using a textbox value? How are you expecting the data from `textBox1` to get to the database when your code never mentions it?

Additionally, as sblom mentions in comments, I'd encourage you to use explicit column names - at which point you won't need to specify anything for `user_id`, which I *assume* is an auto-generated identity column anyway. (It therefore doesn't make sense to try to insert an empty value into it.) It's not clear why you're trying to use an empty *string* as a value for an `Int16` column, either...

EDIT: For your edited code:

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(
   "INSERT INTO niki (name, user_password) VALUES (@name, @user_password)", con);
```

Given your first error, the column is `user_name`, not `name`...

Comment: @John Skeet you was right but now I am getting another error published in my edited post

Comment: @RadostNikolay: No, you haven't fixed the error - you're trying to insert into a column called `name`, but there's no such column. It's called `user_name`. I'm not sure which bit of that you don't understand...

Comment: just post the edit code. I mean I replace the name with user_name but get another error described in the edited post

Comment: @RadostNikolay: In future, please only add a comment saying to look at edited code *after* you've edited it. Now, does your textbox *definitely* have text in it? What happens if you hard-code the value in the parameter, instead of using the text box? (It doesn't help that this is now the *third* problem in a single question...)

Comment: 1st of all I want to applogise that I post the edit after and to say that I am really thankfull that you try to help me. Second I try to hardcode the value and still get the error.

PS: Do you know another way how I can insert the data to mysql database from textboxes. Because if you know there is no reason for us to stay stucked in this one. And one more time really appreciate what you do for me!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just check what table you want to use exactly?

in your actual question it was

```
 da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("Insert into **niki2** values (@id,@name, @user_password)", con);
```

and in updated question the table name is changed to

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO **niki** (name, user_password) VALUES (@name, @user_password)", con);
```

I feel you have two tables you are playing with and are confused

seems like
`name` is in `niki2` and
`user_name` is in `niki` probably your actual table.

I am sure no one can answer with this much ambiguity

Try

**For Table niki**

```
        da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki (user_name, user_password) VALUES (@user_name, @user_password)", con);
```

**For Table niki2**

```
        da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki2 (name, user_password) VALUES (@name, @user_password)", con);
```

**OR Reversal**

Luck

Comment: I just tried it. It is getting me the same error again. 
**Column user_name cannot be null!** 
What I was thinking is may be the problem is in 
*** da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;*** 
Do you any other way how I could do this insert of data from textboxes to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified in the `insert` statement in which fields the values should be stored, so the values will end up in the first three fields in the order that you specified, regardless of their names. I guess that the user name field is the fourth, so it doesn't get a value, thus being null.

Specify which fields should be used:

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO niki (user_id, user_name, user_password) VALUES (@user_id,@user_name, @user_password)", con);
```

Comment: @RadostNikolay: You have to use the actual names of the fields in the table. Obviously `name` is not the correct name for the field that you want to use. The first error message tells us that `user_name` exists in the table, and that is perhaps what you want to use. (The name of the parameter doesn't have to correspond to the field name though, using `@name` is fine.)

Comment: @Gufa I think the problem is somewhere else cause that is my table structure:

#, Column Type, Collation Attributes, Null, Default, Extra

**1 id   int(16)                      No None AUTO_INCREMENT
2 name varchar(255) utf8_general_ci No None      
3 user_password varchar(255) cp1251_general_ci Yes NULL**

Comment: @RadostNikolay: The error messages suggests that there actually is no `name` field and that there is a `user_name` field. Are you looking at the right table, in the right database? Are you showing the actual code that you use? Have you verified that it's actually that code that is running, and not some other code?

Comment: I just double checked whether I am using the correct parameters, but I am still getting this error. What I am thinking now may be the problem is that the system is not receiving the input in the texbox?